# how to SPYDER IDE shows full decimal of value of dataframe columns?

Tags: pandas, spyder

When I import `csv` using pandas dataframe (`read_csv` ),

SPYDER IDE viable show only 2 or 3 decimal, even real decimal is 4.

It works well like 4 decimal, but I wonder SPYDER show only 2 or 3 decimal.

Is there any tips to show full decimal SPYDER variable ?